# What caused traffic on port 631?

Tags: tcp, audit

After I turn on my computer, something triggers tcp packets from localhost with source port 631. I replicated the packets using the command ipptools.

Assuming I got it right, is there a way for me to find out which file/application triggers the call of this command?

The packets are triggered randomly, i.e., x minutes after I turn on my computer.

SIDENOTES: my internet adapters are disabled, and I've denied all incoming traffic and port 631 in my firewall. lsof -i does not list port 631.

Comment: Cups may use it. Just add a iptable rule to log the owner of the packet: services should uses own user and group, if you have a generic `root`, you have a bad system, to start with (or just hacked)

Comment: Port 631 is used for printing (IPP). Something is either trying to print, or (more likely since it's happening without user intervention) trying to see what printers are available.

Comment: What unix variant are you using? Network configuration and audit is very OS-dependent.